# *ngFor quebra o HTML apesar da API estar retornando

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

O Html quebra se eu utilizar o ngForm desse array de Produto, não consegui entender o porque e não aprsenta nenhum erro no console.

O *ngFor funciona nesse mesmo html e component utilizando um array simples.

Service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TokenService } from 'src/app/autenticacao/token.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Produtos } from './lista-produtos';



const API = environment.apiURL;
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  
  export class ListarProdutosService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private tokenService: TokenService) { }

  listaTodosProdutos():Observable<Produtos>{
    return this.http.get<Produtos>(`${API}/produto`);
  }

  deletaProdutoPorId(id:string):Observable<Produtos>{
    return this.http.delete<Produtos>(`${API}/produto/${id}`);
  }
  }
```

Component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Produtos } from './lista-produtos';
import { ListarProdutosService } from './lista-produtos-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista-produtos',
  templateUrl: './lista-produtos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista-produtos.component.css']
})
export class ListaProdutosComponent implements OnInit {
  public paginaAtual = 1;
  @Input() produtos: Produtos = [];

  constructor(private produtosService: ListarProdutosService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.produtosService.listaTodosProdutos().subscribe(produtos => {this.produtos = produtos;
      console.log(this.produtos);
    })
  }
```

Interface:

```
export interface ListaProdutos {

    id: number;
    descricao: string;
    foto: string;
    marca: string;
    nome: string;
    origem: string;
    restricao: string;
    tipoProduto: string;
    usuario: number;
}

    export type Produtos = Array<ListaProdutos>;
```

HTML:

```
<app-header></app-header>

<head>

  <title>Lista Produto</title>

</head>

<!-- Imagem do topo -->
<div class="row">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="../../../assets/img/Topo4.png">
  <p>
    <!-- Título da página -->

    <div class="text-center">
      <h1> PRODUTOS | GLÚTEN </h1>
    </div>

    <p></p>

    <hr class="line2" size="6">
    <!-- Subtítulo da página -->


    <div class="cadastrar">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0"
        style="background-color:#3D6157; border-color:#3D6157; color:white">
        <a routerLink="cadastrar" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: unset;">Cadastrar</a>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Campo de pesquisa
        <nav class="text-center">
          <form class="text-center">
            <input class="text-right" type="search" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Digite sua pesquisa">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" style="background-color: #80aa9e; color:black"
              type="submit">Produto</button>
          </form>
        </nav>

        <!-- Grid para lista dos produtos -->
    <br>
    <ng-container class="container">

      <div class ="row">
        <div *ngFor="let produto of produtos | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: paginaAtual}; let i = index" class="col-12">
                <div class="text-right">
                    <img class="Foto"
                        [src="produto.foto" [alt]="produto.nome" height="90" width="90" style=border-radius:300px>
                    <p></p>
                    <!-- Lixeira -->
                    <button class="btn btn-outline btn-sm" class="btn" style="color:#3D6157"><svg
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash"
                            viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z">
                            </path>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z">
                            </path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <!-- Edição -->
                    <button class="btn-outline btn-sm" class="btn" style="color:#3D6157">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z" />
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="texto">
                        <p>
                        <h5>{{produto.nome}} | {{produto.marca}}</h5>
                        <p> {{produto.descricao}}</p>
                        <hr class="line2" size="4">
        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ng-container>
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)= "paginaAtual = $event" previousLabel="Anterior" nextLabel="Próximo"></pagination-controls>
```

Resultado do get pelo console:

```
{content: Array(4), pageable: {…}, last: true, totalElements: 4, totalPages: 1, …}
content: Array(4)
0:
descricao: "fghfgfhgfhgfg"
foto: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/produto/preview/creme%20de%20leite.jpg"
id: 1
marca: "fgghfghfgh"
nome: "fghfghfg"
origem: "fghfghfgh"
restricao: "LACTOSE"
tipoProduto: "fgfjhgfgh"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {id: 2, nome: 'hkjhkjhkjhkjh', descricao: 'khkjhkjhkjhkj', foto: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/produto/preview/creme%20de%20leite.jpg', restricao: 'LACTOSE', …}
2: {id: 3, nome: 'asdasdsad', descricao: 'asdasdasdas', foto: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/produto/preview/creme%20de%20leite.jpg', restricao: 'LACTOSE', …}
3: {id: 4, nome: 'dfgdfgdfg', descricao: 'dfgdgdfgdfgdfg', foto: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/produto/preview/creme%20de%20leite.jpg', restricao: 'LACTOSE', …}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
empty: false
first: true
last: true
number: 0
numberOfElements: 4
pageable: {sort: {…}, offset: 0, pageNumber: 0, pageSize: 10, paged: true, …}
size: 10
sort: {empty: false, sorted: true, unsorted: false}
totalElements: 4
totalPages: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Olhando o código vc já está atribuindo na variável `produtos` o retorno da API, ou seja, tudo que a API entrega, mas creio que o que precisa seja apenas o que está em **`content`** que é um array com os produtos. Outra coisa que percebi, se vc está preenchendo a variável `produtos` com o retorno da API pq colocou **`@Input()`** na variável?

Comment: @LeAndrade eu retirei o **@input** mas não resolveu. Em relação à parte do retorno, como eu poderia fazer para retornar apenas o **content**?

Comment: o retorno que você tem da api é de um json com o conteudo dentro do atributo content. onde você recebe (produtos) => { this.produtos = produtos}
troque para: **(produtos) => { this.produtos = produtos.content }**
obs:  no html a tag <img class="Foto"  [src="produto.foto"... esta sem o fechamento do **[** no atributo src. troque para **<img class="Foto"  [src]="produto.foto"...**